# Enlarged display of Visual-Studio window

Tags: visual-studio

Visual-Studio is displaying enlarged character so that it is impossible to use it. How to zoom down the application so that it displays all commands in the window in a readable and usable manner?

Comment: This is probably that kind of question that requires an image to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom left of each editor is a zoom control:

[image: zoom control]

Clicking on that will allow typing in a new percentage, so selection from the drop down.